# Help with disjoint cycle decomposition and finding image/pre-image of a S8 group

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics

i have this exercise and i'm confused about the part where i find the image and pre-image.

[image]

I solved it for 5 in alfpha, found the image and preimage (preimage is number that 5 results from and image is the number that 5 transforms into).
I found the disjoint cycles of both alpha and beta.

Now, how exactly do i proceed for finding the image and pre-image of those ?
I know the exercise doesn't ask for pre-image but i have others where it does, and also asks for the length.

This is how i solved. How do i proceed to finding image/pre-image ?

[image]

Thank you

Comment: It appears like you have solved the problem completely - representing both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in disjoint cycle decomposition form, and computing the image and preimage of $5$ under $\alpha$. What exactly is your question?  You can similarly compute the image and preimage of other points (besides $5$) under $\alpha$.

Comment: My question is, which one is the image and preimage of alfa and beta ? Not the one for 5 under alfa, but the one for the disjoint cycles ? As you can see the exercise besides image/preimage of 5, asks also for "alfa and beta in disjoint cycles -> AND calculate their image." Do i already have image and preimage of alfa and beta without even knowing it ? Which one is it ? I'm confused.

Comment: Usually you compute the image or preimage only of points in the domain or codomain, not of functions. Maybe there is a mistake in the wording of the question.

Comment: The function alpha is a permutation, and its image is the set of all 8 points. But the definition of the image of a function is trivial in the case of permutations.

Comment: Ok so basically they gave me a normal cycle of an S8 group which is alpha, a cycle composition beta, and I have to transform both in disjoint cycles. To do that for Alfa it's simple, but for beta I need to first transform it into a normal cycle, then into disjoint. Once I find the disjoint cycles I can find image and preimage of any number in that group S8. Right ? For example image and preimage for 7 in beta is 5 and 1 respectively.

Comment: So alpha is a permutation and beta is a composition of cycles to start with ?

Comment: Yes, for 7 is 5 and 1 under beta. But both alpha and beta are permutations. A permutation is a bijection from a set to itself, and can expressed in two row form, or as a composition of cycles, or as a composition of disjoint cycles. The latter form is simplest and it is possible to express in that form always.

Comment: Similar to saying f(x) =3x+2, and image of 2 under f is 8.

Comment: Ok so a group S8 is of course of permutations, and those forms that i wrote are the representations of those permutations. To go from two row form to disjoint is one step, to go from composition form to disjoint form i have to go first to (two row form) then go to disjoint. And all 3 represent the same thing . Right ?

Comment: Yes. You could go from composition form to disjoint in one step.